# Unit test for custom JsonConverter

Tags: c#, json.net, xunit, jsonconverter

In my application, I need some parts of the application where I need to have EscapeHtml to escape special characters in string, but not global.

I created a custom `JsonConverter` class:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Shared
{
    public class EscapingHtmlConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public EscapingHtmlConverter()
        {
        }

        public override bool CanRead => true;

        public override bool CanWrite => false;

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => objectType == typeof(string);

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.String)
            {
                var res = ((string)reader.Value)?.Trim() == string.Empty ? null : ((string)reader.Value)?.Trim();

                return res == null ? null : JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                                            res,
                                            Formatting.None,
                                            new JsonSerializerSettings
                                            { StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml });
            }

            return reader.Value;
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

and in model use attribute

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(EscapingHtmlConverter))]
public string PropertyName { get; set; }
```

I need a unit test for a custom `JsonConverter` and I try to do it this way:

```
using Xunit;
using Shared;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace Shared.Tests
{
    public class EscapingHtmlConverterTests
    {

        [Fact()]
        public void ReadJsonTest()
        {
            Model model = new Model()
            {
                PropertyToNotBeEscaped = "Something that do not need to be escaped",
                PropertyToBeEscaped = "Some string <with> [special] 'characters' & more",                
            }; 

            var expectedResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model.PropertyToBeEscaped, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml
            });

            JsonReader reader = new JTokenReader(JToken.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model.PropertyToBeEscaped)));
            var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            var converter = new EscapingHtmlConverter();

            // just for debugging
            Assert.NotNull(model.PropertyToBeEscaped);
            Assert.NotNull(reader);
            Assert.NotNull(serializer);

            // Act
            var result = converter.ReadJson(reader, model.propertyTobeEscaped.GetType(), "Some string <with> [special] 'characters' & more", serializer);
            Assert.Equal(expectedResult, result?.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

But test failed

```
Message: 
Assert.Equal() Failure
Expected: "Some string \u003cwith\u003e [special] \u0027characters\u0027 \u0026 more"
Actual:   (null)
```

I am not sure about the last part of the test - parameters that I should pass to `JsonConverter`

Comment: What was your intention here: `Assert.NotNull(typeof(string))`?

Comment: @PeterCsala just typo, thx

Comment: Can you please fix the Act part as well? `model.propertyTobeEscaped` >> `model.PropertyToBeEscaped`

Answer (score 2):

After performing a quick debugging it turned out that your guard expression (`reader.TokenType == JsonToken.String`) returns `false` in your test that's why the result is `null`

One way to fix this is by calling the `reader.Read` before the guard expression. *I've transformed your guard expression to an early exit to streamline your code.*

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    reader.Read();
    if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.String)
       return reader.Value;
    
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thx. This solve my problem with unit test, but broke functionality outside of test :(

Comment: @SasaJovanovic Could you please elaborate on this, how did it break the functionality?